# Xpath clicking not working at all

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, element

Quick info: I'm using Mac OS, Python 3.

I have like 800 links that need to be clicked on a page (and many more pages to go so need automation).

They were hidden because you only see those links when you hover over.
I fixed that by injecting CSS rule (just saying in case its the reason it's not working).

When I try to find elements by xpath it does not want to click the links afterwards and it also doesn't find all of them always just 4 (even when more are displayed in view).

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="Display">Display</a>
```

When i click ok copy xpath in inspect it gives me:

```
//*[@id="tiles"]/li[3]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a
```

But it doesn't work when I use it like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tiles"]/li[3]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
```

So two questions:

1. How do I get them all?
2. How do I get it to click on each of them?

The pattern in the XPath is the same, with the `/li[3]` being the only number that changes, for this I created a for loop to create them all based on the count on page which I did successfully.

So if it can be done with the XPaths generated by myself that are corresponding to when I copy XPath in inspector then I only need question 2 answered.

PS.: this is HTML of parent of that first HTML:

```
<li onclick="openPopup(event, 'collect', {item_id: 165214})" class="collect" data-item-id="165214"><a href="#" title="Display">Display</a></li>
```

Comment: When posting code here, make sure your code is indented using the code tool (`{}`). With HTML in particular, you will find that the code disappears unless you format it.

Comment: `find_elements_by_get()`? Shouldn't that be `find_elements_by_xpath()`?

Comment: yes sorry its like you said in my code it was a retype from me

Comment: Did you also typo the HTML, because you're having to go through an awful lot of back-and-forth with your answerers in comments, which indicates that you've likely failed to provide a real **[mcve]** of your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry new to this so (coding and asking questions about it)

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//a[.="Display"]
```

will select all `a` links with anchor text equal to `"Display"`.

Comment: Same answer as for @DebanjanB gives me nothing in return no error it just finishes the code without result. (Process finished with exit code 0)

Comment: also i did i count check to see if any element is found and got 0 as response. (created variable count and added 1 in for loop)

Comment: Then you've reported improperly when you said `<a href="#" title="Display">Display</a>` is in the HTML, or it's in a frame you've not accounted for, or it's not created dynamically after your XPath evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, the `HTML` you have shared and your code attempts there is no necessity to get the `<li>` tags. Instead we will get the `<a>` tags in a list. So to answer your first question `How do I get them all` you can use the following line of code :

```
all_Display = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tiles']//li/div[2]/ul/li[@class='collect']/a[@title='Display']")
```

Next `to click on each of them` you have to create a `loop` to iterate through all the `<a>` tag as follows :

```
all_Display = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tiles']//li/div[2]/ul/li[@class='collect']/a[@title='Display']")
for each_Display in all_Display :
    each_Display.click()
```

Comment: Ok, first I created a variable called each_Display and put the code you suggested. But I got nothing in return (Process finished with exit code 0). Also i tried without the variable each_Display which also gave me same result. (no errors, just empty result)

Comment: also i did i count check to see if any element is found and got 0 as response.  (created variable count and added 1 in for loop)

Comment: @breinvis That essentially means the xpath which you have forced on us to work with is not uniquely identifying the element. Share the relevant HTML.

Comment: https://displate.com/eddie/gaming-characters . (new to coding so I don't know what is relevant to it...

Comment: Which elements exactly are you trying to collect with text as `Display`?

Comment: The button that says Display on every image on that page, the collect is what it says in the code. What happens is when I do it manually is it will ask me to add to an album.

Comment: Honestly, I don't find any text as `Display` neither on the `Website` nor on the `HTML`

Comment: The screenshot is when you hover over one of the images and then get the overlay with those options

Comment: I only get those options when I visit with chrome I don't have those options in firefox or safari etc

Comment: Unfortunately the `Like` / `Display` / `Share`, `Twitt` & `Report` option doesn't renders on current version of `Chrome`. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Using an XPath with elements by position is not ideal. Instead use a CSS selector to match the attributes for the targeted elements.

Something like:

```
all_Display = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#tiles li[onclick][data-item-id] a[title]")
```

You can then click them in a loop if none of them is loading a new page:

```
for element in all_Display:
    element.click()
```

Comment: Got errors:             
          selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#tiles li[onclick][data-item-id] a[title]"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)

Comment: `find_elements_by_css_selector` doesn't raise `NoSuchElementException` unless you've defined an implicit wait. Make sure that the targeted elements are not in frame. Other than that you should get some elements since it matches the HTML you've provided.

Comment: I read the error code in your case and the problem was elsewhere, I ran your suggestion again with 0 on my counter and exit code 0